# seaborn factor plot: Plotting columns with lists instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have created a dataframe as follows

[image]

As you can see, some columns (`mean_fit_time, mean_score, mean_score_time`) have lists instead of values. Now I would like to make a boxplot of the mean fit time for each estimator. If the table is organized in a long format (individual values instead of list), I can do it with a seaborn boxplot as follows

```
seaborn.boxplot(x='name', y='mean_fit_time', data=dataframe)
```

However, in this case, I get the following error

```
ValueError: Neither the `x` nor `y` variable appears to be numeric.
```

Do I have to explode the dataframe so that there is only one value in each cell or is there any other efficient method for handling this?

**Note**: BTW, Can someone tell me how I can share a dataframe in stackoverflow so that it is reproducible by others.

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue here is your dataframe. It is in a rather messy format. You have cells containing dicts and lists; not what seaborn wants. You want it all on one level with cells containing strings or numbers.

Comment: Do you know how I can explode the dataframe so that I have a series of numbers instead of lists

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Sorry. The easiest thing might be to split the data into 5 bits before making it a dataframe but as I dont know how you are getting this I couldn't say for sure.